# VBA code to search for a row header, and select the entire range beneath that header

Tags: vba, excel

I'm VERY new to VBA and i'm trying to automate some of my day to day tasks.  One task that I would like to automate requires me to "search" for a specified header, and select that entire column of data.  I will then paste that range into a different spreadsheet.

`Tamcolumn = Cells.Find(what:="plan_tamaward", after:="a1", searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlBycolumn, lookat:=xlPart).Column`

I've found this little bit of code to be helpful when i'm defining an entire column, the problem is I can't define the column header and define the range below without "selecting" the data - which I know is a big no-no.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `application.worksheetfunction.match("plan_tamarard",worksheets("name").range("a1:z1"),false)` get's the column  and use `resize` to set the length of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can incorporate the following approach into your code...

```
Dim Col As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
If Application.CountIf(Rows(1), "plan_tamaward*") > 0 Then
    Col = Application.Match("plan_tamaward*", Rows(1), 0)
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))
End If
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox Rng.Address
    'do whatever you want to do with this range here
Else
    MsgBox "The column named like plan_tamaward* was not found in Row1.", vbExclamation, "Column Not Found!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: This is great.  Is there some way that I could change the code from a Application.countif, to something like worksheet("x").countif?  I'm going to be running the Macro from another workbook, and copying the rng from this workbook, to that other.

Comment: You just need to qualify the range inside the CountIf with the sheet where you want to search the string plan_tamaward*. So in this case it should be If Application.CountIf(Worksheets("X").Rows(1), "plan_tamaward*") > 0 and same way you will need to change the lookup range in the Match function also.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!  Now I just have the last step of setting the values of the range that i'm copying = to the ranges I've set

this is the code that I have, but when I run it, it copies the data from working sheet.

wbmodel.Sheets("Copyto").Range("F4").Resize(Rngm.Rows.Count).Value = Rngm.Value
    wbmodel.Sheets("Copyto").Range("E4").Resize(RngSku.Rows.Count, 1).Value = RngSku.Value
    wbmodel.Sheets("Copyto").Range("C4").Resize(RngPO.Rows.Count).Value = RngPO.Value
End Sub

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!  Now I just have the last step of setting the values of the new range = rng (I changed the variable to be rngm,rngsku,rngpo)

this is the code that I have, but when I run it, it copies the data from "copyto" .  it's like the variables are overwritten, but when I check the address, they are correct.

wbmodel.Sheets("Copyto").Range("F4").Resize(Rngm.Rows.Count).Value = Rngm.Value
    wbmodel.Sheets("Copyto").Range("E4").Resize(RngSku.Rows.Count, 1).Value = RngSku.Value
    wbmodel.Sheets("Copyto").Range("C4").Resize(RngPO.Rows.Count).Value = RngPO.Value
End Sub

Comment: Please open a new question. :)